# how to load image from subfolder of resources

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

hi i created a new group in my code and put the all images in that now resources\CountryFlags is the path i am doing this

```
NSString *fileName = countryInfo.ImageUrl;
CCSprite *flag ;

NSString * fullPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: [fileName stringByDeletingPathExtension]
ofType: [fileName pathExtension]
inDirectory: @"CountryFlags"];
if (fullPath)
{
    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: fullPath];
    if (theImage)
    {
       flag = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage: [theImage CGImage] key: fileName];
       flag.position = ccp(200, 265);
       flag.scale = .255;
    }
}
```

but fullpath always got nil and not getting the code so any one have any idea how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because there is no "CountryFlags" folder in your app's bundle. XCode does not copy directory structure of resources unless folders are added as folder references (blue folder icons in project navigator, not yellow).